# Create a Unique Sequential ID Generator - Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to find a way to create a google scripts function that will create unique sequential ID generator after looking through my google sheets document verifying that it will be a unique ID. I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58515330/14143011 which is exactly what I need however I do not want the ID to be inserted into the google sheet automatically, as I want to be able to use the ID in another function I am working on. When it comes to the date I am using this google scripts function to retrieve the current date:

```
const timezone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

function datestamp() {
  var datestamp_format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, datestamp_format);
}
```

To clarify what I am attempting to do, I have this function which creates folders for files I am uploading:

```
function createSubfolder(){
  var dropbox = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "US/Eastern", "_yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I want to change the name to also contain the generated ID. I want the 'createSubfolder' function to call the function that generates the ID and return it to a variable such as this:

```
function createSubfolder(){
      var generatedID = idGeneratorFunction()
      var dropbox = generatedID + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "US/Eastern", "_yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution writes the ID using this statement

```
sheet.getRange(2, indexId + 1, newId.length).setValues(newId);
```

Just comment it out and change the customer function to return the ID and then you can use it however you like.

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended solution:**

Instead of setting the `newID` value into the sheet via `sheet.getRange(2, indexId + 1, newId.length).setValues(newId)`, you can pass the `newID` value to the createSubfolder function through a parameter. Just edit last lines of the `autoid_(sheet)` function and call your `createSubfolder(newId)` function as seen below:

****UPDATED****

[image]

See this edited full script below from the referenced [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513757/automatically-generate-a-unique-sequential-id-in-google-sheets/58515330#58515330):

```
/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet} sheet
 */
function autoid_(sheet) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  if (data.length < 2) return;
  var indexId = data[0].indexOf('ID');
  var indexDate = data[0].indexOf('DATE');
  if (indexId < 0 || indexDate < 0) return;
  var id = data.reduce(
    function(p, row) {
      var year =
        row[indexDate] && row[indexDate].getTime
          ? row[indexDate].getFullYear() % 100
          : '-';
      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p.indexByGroup, year)) {
        p.indexByGroup[year] = [];
      }
      var match = ('' + row[indexId]).match(/(\d+)-(\d+)/);
      var idVal = row[indexId];
      if (match && match.length > 1) {
        idVal = match[2];
        p.indexByGroup[year].push(+idVal);
      }
      p.ids.push(idVal);
      p.years.push(year);
      return p;
    },
    { indexByGroup: {}, ids: [], years: [] }
  );

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(id, null, '  '));

  var newId = data
    .map(function(row, i) {
      if (row[indexId] !== '') return [row[indexId]];
      if (isNumeric(id.years[i])) {
        var lastId = Math.max.apply(
          null,
          id.indexByGroup[id.years[i]].filter(function(e) {
            return isNumeric(e);
          })
        );
        lastId = lastId === -Infinity ? 1 : lastId + 1;
        id.indexByGroup[id.years[i]].push(lastId);
        return [
          Utilities.formatString(
            '%s-%s',
            id.years[i],
            ('000000000' + lastId).slice(-3)
          )
        ];
      }
      return [''];
    })
    .slice(1);
      //Instead of setting the value on sheet, add createSubfolder function below:
      createSubfolder(newId);// Pass the newID value to the createSubfolder() parameter (inside the parenthesis) to "generatedID" as seen
    }
    
    function createSubfolder(generatedID){ // Edit your createSubfolder function with a parameter named generatedID (inside the parenthesis)
      var dropbox = generatedID + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "US/Eastern", "_yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. My program right now is uploading folders and what I want is to name these folders with the generated ID. I am unsure of how to call the function autoid_(sheet) to begin with.

Comment: I've updated my post to more clarify my situation.

Comment: I have updated my answer for more clarity. You do not need to call the autoid_(sheet) as it is the main function to run. Just edit the autoid_(sheet) function's last lines, as seen on my updated answer.

Comment: This still wont work for me as I am calling the createSubfolder from my JavaScript code not my google scripts code. Is there a way to call autoid_(sheet) from my javascript and have it return the ID there so I can then pass it into my createSubfolder function?

Comment: Have you tried putting return newId; on the autoid_(sheet) last line? This will return the newID value when you call auto_(sheet) function.

Comment: yes but the problem is that I can not call autoid for whatever reason. I believe it has something to do with the underscore at the end.

Comment: Yes, that is actually right. I'm also unable to replicate the script earlier but it looks like there are also missing functions that were not included from the answer like isNumeric() as it is non-existing. The reference link the poster has included, https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/spreadsheet_autoid/autoid.js is no longer available too.