# Function to add unique/sequential ID to row after new entries based on another jobname

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with a list of job names in column F. Each job name can appear multiple times in the list and I need to count or add a unique ID into another column in the same row for every new Jobname entered in column F.

The caveat is, the entries in column F can be "penciled" meaning a value will be entered before it is added to the dropdown list that validates column F (a named range called "JobList"). Those entries should not have a unique ID added.

I've seen a few different solutions online and wondering what could be the best option for my requirements to proceed with. Linked below

> [Automatically generate a unique sequential ID in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513757/automatically-generate-a-unique-sequential-id-in-google-sheets)

> https://yagisanatode.com/2019/02/09/google-apps-script-create-custom-unique-ids-in-google-sheets/

Apologies if we are not allowed to link other sites, I will remove immediately if so.

Currently, I'm thinking of building this solution

- Function1 to return number of times jobname appears in Col F
- Function2 to add +1 to Function1 (unless its 1) and append to row
- onEdit(e) > update this function to call Function2 when Col F is edited and send parameters of current row and value (jobname)

Seems like it could work - will come back with my progress

---- UPDATE ---
I have made a function that seems to work, it does take about 8 seconds to run, however, and seems like it could be prone to issues on many edits, but any onEdit function I think would behave in a similar way.

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var jobname = e.value;
  var count = 0;
  
  var job = jobname;
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Calendar v2");
  var joblist = sh.getRange("F:F").getValues();
  
  if(sheet=="Calendar v2" && col==6){
  //range.setNote(sheet+' + '+row+' + '+col+' + '+jobname+ 'Last modified: ' + new Date());
   // count = countJobname();
  
  for (var i=0;i<joblist.length;i++){
    if(joblist[i]==job){
    count = count + 1;
      Logger.log(count);
    }  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet).getRange(row,15).setValue("TRIGGER "+count);
  
  }
  }
}
```

I did build out *working* separate functions but for some reason, they were not working when called in onEdit, I rebuilt the onEdit function line by line and it eventually worked, will rework the functions back in but still open to suggestions if anyone has a better method. Still a rookie at this stuff :)

Another UPDATE

- the last setValue line was running inside the for loop, badly formatted code introduces the dumbest problems. it runs almost instantly now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the revised code, it's a pretty simple solution and hits the core functionality and I will be building it out further to provide unique ID codes based off 2 columnns (Jobname + Category).

I haven't added the check for "pencil" entries, currently it checks all values in column F.

To implement that check instead we would add the commented code instead in the countJobname function find the Named Range instead

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var jobname = e.value;
  var count = 0;
  
  
  if(sheet=="Calendar v2" && col==6){
   count = countJobname(jobname);
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet).getRange(row,15).setValue("TRIGGER "+count);
    
  }

}



function countJobname(jobname){
  
  var job = jobname;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Calendar v2");
  var joblist = sheet.getRange("F:F").getValues(); //.getRangeByName("JobList").getValues();
  var count = 0;
  
  for (var i=0;i<joblist.length;i++){
    if(joblist[i]==job){
    count = count + 1;
      Logger.log(count);
    } 
  
  }return count
  
}
```