# Automatically generate an id including current year in Google Sheets using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want a 4 digits unique sequential ID to be generated when a row is added to a Google sheet using following format YYXX (YY indicating current year, XX indicating sequential number), something similar as displayed in following gif:

[This gif has a hardcoded solution only for those 3 rows, just as an example for this post.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu6TI.gif)

I have tried with solution provided in the following similar question but it didn't work for me and I don't have enough reputation to comment there:
[Automatically generate a unique sequential ID in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513757/automatically-generate-a-unique-sequential-id-in-google-sheets)

Thanks in advance for collaborations!!

Comment: 1. How the rows will be added? It will me manual filling column B or some automatic update? 2. If a filled cell in column B will be changed, should the ID in column A be updated as well? Or cells in B should not be changed?

Comment: Thanks for helping me with those questions, I am really amateur on this.
1. Rows will be added automatically by an external form.
2. If a value in a row already created in row B is changed, ID in row A should not be updated.

Comment: What should happen after the counter XX reached 99? It will be reset to 00? Or it will be 100, then 101, 102, etc?

Comment: I am not planning to have more than 100 record per year.
But in case that happens I would say the best would be continue with 100, 101, 102...

Comment: Ok. Basically scripts can't be fired other than manually. Except some cases. Submitting a form is the case. So you have a form. Do you? You fill the form and submit it. All the data from the form automatically is append to the linked spreadsheet. Do you have the one? Usually column A of the first sheet of the spreadsheet contains dates. And you want to have another sheet which column A contains IDs?

Comment: It appears to me that you have a bunch of requirements that are not really necessary for your actual purpose. If you want to create unique IDs in column A as column B is populated, you can do for example `=arrayformula(if(isblank(B2:B),,right(to_text(year(today())),2)&right(0&to_text(row(B:B)),2)))`. You use `arrayformula` and `if(isblank(...` to centralize the formulas. (Native formulas are better for computational efficiency.) And you can use `row(...)` index to create unique IDs. I included some example functions (`to_text`, `right`, `concat` via `&`) for manipulating text.

Comment: However, if you require the year from the time a cell is initially populated, then you have 2 options. One is for you to get the timestamp from your form. Another one is to use Apps Script. There is no native function to get timestamp of the edit action. Another requirement that seems superfluous to me is the reset of ID increment by year. With helper column, that can also be done with native functions, but efforts do not seem justified.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question with your precise requirements -- if things come from form submission and you want timestamp for that, you should clarify. I do still suggest you review your requirements.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will edit my question so it has all information and it is more complete.
Actually my sheet is populated from 2 places: 1. AppSheet and 2. Google Forms.

Comment: _populated from 2 places: 1. AppSheet and 2. Google Forms_ — I just added the example how to handle form submitting. As for the 'AppSheet' it depends on what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
// this function fires automatically after submitting of the form

function set_ID() {
  // get first sheet of the spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];

  // get the last row index
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();

  // get two last numbers of current year
  var year = (new Date()).getFullYear().toString().slice(2);

  // if sheet is empty, no responses --> set the ID in the cell A2 
  if (last_row == 2) {
    sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(year + '01');
    return;
  }

  // if the sheet contains previous responses and IDs

  // get the previous ID
  var previous_ID = sheet.getRange('A' + (last_row-1)).getDisplayValue(); 

  // get the previous counter and increase it
  var counter = parseInt(previous_ID.slice(2)) + 1;

  //  add zero for nums 1..9
  if (counter < 10) counter = '0' + counter;

  // set the ID in column A of the last row
  sheet.getRange('A'+last_row).setValue(year + counter); 
}


// this function should be run just once to install the trigger

function install_onFormSubmitTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('set_ID').forSpreadsheet(ss).onFormSubmit().create();
}
```

The sheet with responses:

[image]

Form:

[image]

After submit the form the installed trigger `onFormSubmit()` fires the function `set_ID()` that calculates year and counter and set it into column A.

Comment: Thanks Yuri!!
So, Should I only paste that code in a new App Script? Or do I need to customize any value?

Comment: You can try. I don't know how your form looks like. You have to add a linked spreadsheet to your form and put the code into Script Editor of this spreadsheet. Then you have to install the trigger (run the second function `install_onFormSubmitTrigger()`). Then it makes sense to try to run the first function just once to get the required permissions. And then you can try to make a submit from your form.