# Generate unique incremental serial number for multiple discrete participants

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to use a Google Sheet to log clinical specimens for a trial. Each of the many participants in this trial will have a unique Study ID (generated elsewhere) and they will submit multiple samples over many months so lots of samples linked to each Study ID and many Study IDs.

I plan to use a Google Form for quick data capture into a single worksheet of a Google Sheet (e.g. Study ID, date sample taken, date received, nature of specimen). Each row will relate to a single specimen.

On data entry into the sheet, I would like Google Sheets to generate a unique serial number (a "specimen ID") in the format StudyID/sequential 4 digit number. For example, if study ID = SAC030 and its their third submitted sample, the specimen ID = SAC030/0003. Their next sample would be SAC030/0004 but this might be received weeks-months later with multiple other samples from other people in between.

Therefore the issue is finding the most recent entry for this participant and continuing the sequential 4 digit number from there as opposed to just adding 1 to the last specimen ID in the sheet. None of the other variables e.g. sample type or dates need to be taken into account when forming the specimen ID. Would prefer a script solution ideally as this will be used by lots of users so feel like that might be most robust but will take any help!

This would be the target output:

[image]

This post seems very close to my issue but I'm not skilled enough with google scripts to adapt the code to my scenario: [Automatically generate a unique sequential ID in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513757/automatically-generate-a-unique-sequential-id-in-google-sheets)

Comment: This site is for anyone who write code to make **specific** questions about coding like writing code, fixing code, using tools to write/fix code. Considering this, please show what you tried to adapt  your findings to your needs or make a more specific question rather than vaguely asking for help. Is there is something that you don't understand about the linked question? Whenever be possible use text rather than images, i.e. use markdown to add a table of the target output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const osh = e.source.getSheetByName("Output Data Sheet Name")
  const studyId = e.namedValues["Study Id"][0];
  const sampleDate = e.namedValues["Sample_date"][0];
  const checkedInDate = e.namedValues["Checked_in_date"][0];
  const sampleType = e.namedValues["Sample_type"][0];
  const specId;
  let col = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().reduce((a,h,i) => (a[h]=i+1,a),{});
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,col["StudyId"],e.range.rowStart - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat().filter(e => e.slice(0,6) == studyId);
  if(vs.length > 0) {
    let n = 4 - vs.length.toString().length;
    specId = `${studyId}/${"0".repeat(n)}${vs.length + 1}`
  } else {
    specId = `${studyId}/0001`;
  }
  let o = [[studyId,sampleDate,checkedInDate,sampleType,specId]];
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and reply @Cooper. Unfortunately I'm struggling to get this to work. Am I correct in thinking you've written this to recognise a G Form entry as the trigger? I've tried changing this to a simple onEdit(e) trigger and I've also tried updating the variable names so they match my output sheet for both triggers but no luck. There is also a warning re syntax error re line 9, am I right in thinking the constant specId hasnt been defined? Thanks again.

Comment: You have to create an onMyFormSubmit trigger. By going to the triggers section of the editor or you can do it programmatically as well